# Implementing Distributed discrete event simulator

Tags: distributed-computing, distributed-system

I have recently been exploring distributed simulation for a college term project. I have gone through a lot a reference materials, including:

1. Parallel and Distributed Discrete Event Simulation: Algorithms And Applications: Richard M. Fujimoto
2. Distributed Discrete-Event Simulation: Jayadev Misra
3. Integrated Fluid and Packet Network Simulations: George F. Riley, Talal M. Jaafar, Richard M. Fujimoto
4. Parallel Simulation of Telecommunication Networks: http://titania.ctie.monash.edu.au/pnetsim.html
5. Introduction to Discrete-Event Simulation and the SimPy Language: Norm Matloff
6. The OMNET++ Discrete Event Simulation System: András Varga

I wish to begin building an actual Distributed discrete event simulator system, such as for Digital logic simulators, Network simulators, etc.

I want to build such a system from scratch. I wish to know some references for building this system.